# Could I use Lagrangian mechanics for high school physics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, education

I love learning maths and I already have a high level in calculus (up to the basis of PDES), way more than enough to use Lagrangian mechanics. However, we haven’t started physics classes at my school yet. Are high school, pre-calculus physics possible to solve using the Lagrangian?
Edit: my teacher doesn’t care and says that if learning 4 years of math on your own is worthy of a good grade.

Comment: The question should go to your teacher - if they can't understand what you did, they can't grade it. If they can understand what you did and you're avoiding doing the work they want you to, they may give you poor marks anyway.

Comment: Euler Lagrange equation involves partial derivatives, which are mid-level calculus. Partial derivatives are not introduced in high school afaik. Nevertheless, partial derivatives are a trivial extension ordinary derivatives.

Answer (score 3):

The Lagrangian formalism would not be useful in a high school physics class. In essentially any case where it would be *possible* to apply it, the Euler-Lagrange equations simply reduce to the familiar Newton's 2nd law.

There are exceptions to this - particularly motion along an incline and the simple pendulum. These are examples of *constrained motion*, which the Lagrangian formalism is particularly adept at handling. However, the *reason* the Lagrangian formalism is useful for such situations is that it allows you to basically ignore the constraint forces (tension, normal force, etc) - but those forces are *precisely* what you will be actually studying in an introductory physics course, so the ability to ignore them is in this case a bug, not a feature.

Of course, after you study them in a more traditional context you may find it very interesting to re-do the analysis from the Lagrangian perspective.